# where is ip_rcv function in linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, socket.io

i want to find ip_rcv() function in my linux but i cant.i search ubuntu and fedora and centos but i cant find this function.but in http://lxr.free-electrons.com
give these eferences :
ip_rcv
Defined as a function prototype in:

```
include/net/ip.h, line 108
```

Defined as a function in:

```
net/ipv4/ip_input.c, line 405
```

Referenced (in 3 files total) in:

```
net/ipv4/af_inet.c, line 1751
net/ipv4/ip_input.c, line 405
include/net/ip.h, line 108
```

but i cant find anything.

Comment: `Defined as a function` -- you need that one.

Answer (score 1):

From [Linux Source Code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ip_input.c) `ip_rcv()` is in `net/ipv4/ip_input.c` define as the Main IP Receive routine.

Have a look to this paper about Linux IP Stack: [IP Layer
Implementation of Linux Kernel Stack](https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/70789059/linux-kernel-ip.pdf).

Comment: do you mean in /usr/include/net/ipv4/ip_input.c   ?????
i use this :
me@localhost :/ #  find -name ip_input.c in / directory but it found nothing.

Comment: `ip_rcv` is a Closed Kernel Functions. Do you want to use it directly?

Comment: yes i want to get data from this function  i mean i want to interfere in kernel method. can i do ?????????????
molivier you are  kind and thanks for your attention ..
if you know something tell me please.

Comment: i can fin ip_rcv ,now i need Linux/net/ipv4/ip_input.c direct path beacuse ip_rcv is in ip_input.c
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c  
line 405

Answer (score 0):

`ip_rcv()` is in `net/ipv4/ip_input.c`. The source code is in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/net/ipv4/ip_input.c#L406.